# Android : google-cloud-language library on backend cause appengineEnhance FAILED

Tags: android, google-app-engine

To use google-cloud natural language on my app backend, I added following Gradle dependency :

```
compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-language:0.9.2-alpha'
```

which cause, when added, :

> Execution failed for task 'appbackend:appengineEnhance'.
>   An error occurred enhancing DataNucleus classes.

Running with --stacktrace, --debug, --info give too much output with no clues.
Please thanks for help as I cannot find no information in documentation on how to handle properly this google cloud api with appengine.

The full gradle for my backend is as per below :

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.38'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.38'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.38'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.38'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'

    compile ('com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.0.3'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }
    compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'

    //JBE
    compile files('libs/java-json.jar')
    compile files('libs/jersey-server-1.1.5.jar') //what is that?
    compile files('libs/org.apache.commons.httpclient_3.1.0.v201012070820.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-services-sqladmin-v1beta1-rev9-1.15.0-rc.jar')


    compile 'org.ow2.asm:asm:4.0'
    compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jpa:3.1.3'
    compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jdo:3.1.3'
    compile 'com.google.appengine.orm:datanucleus-appengine:2.1.2'
    compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:3.1.3'
    compile 'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec:1.0'
   // compile ('javax.jdo:jdo-api:3.0.1')
   // compile 'javax.transaction:jta:1.1'

    //cloud storage
    compile 'com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.4.4'
    //Google Cloud Natural Language API
    compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-language:0.9.2-alpha'
    //compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-language:v1-rev373-1.22.0'
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }

    enhancer { 
        version = "v2"
        api="jpa"
        enhanceOnBuild = true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok as usual I feel google api documentation confusing :

presentation of google cloud APIs which include Google Cloud Natural Language API let you thing you can use it on app engine

http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.9.2/index.html
with comments "... if you are running on Google App Engine or Compute Engine, the private key is automatically detected..."

but in java-docs-samples

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/language/analysis
it is noted :"Note The Natural Language client is not supported by App Engine Standard."

So hopefully  it is temporary due to current alpha state of these libraries